# Validating the implementation of the Decorator Pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I am learning hands on implementation of Design Patterns.  The following is an implementation of the Decorator Design Pattern.  I would like to know if the implementation is correct.  Let me know if it can be improved or is incorrect.

```
interface Markable
{
    void mark();
}
class SingleMarker implements Markable
{

    @Override
    public void mark() {
        System.out.println("Single Marker");

    }
}
class MarkerDecorator implements Markable
{
    protected SingleMarker singleMarker;
    public MarkerDecorator(final SingleMarker singleMarker) {
        this.singleMarker = singleMarker;
    }
    @Override
    public void mark() {
        this.singleMarker.mark();
    }
}
class MultipleMarker extends MarkerDecorator
{
    private int numberOfMarks;
    public MultipleMarker(SingleMarker singleMarker) {
        this(singleMarker, 2);
    }
    public MultipleMarker(SingleMarker singleMarker, int numberOfMarks) {
        super(singleMarker);
        this.numberOfMarks = numberOfMarks;
    }
    @Override
    public void mark() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMarks; i++) {
            super.singleMarker.mark();
        }
    }

}
```

- P.S.

  If this question is inappropriate for this forum, please let me know.

Comment: you should raise it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a better fit for this question.

Comment: Can the moderators migrate this question?  If not I can do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only improvement is to **program against interfaces and not implementations**.

1. Use the `Markable` interface instead of `SingleMarker` in `MarkerDecorator` and `MultipleMarker`.
2. It is also a question why `MultipleMarker` need to extend `MarkerDecorator` instead of directly implementing the interface. It your case it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  Will improve the implementation.  Your second question is very valid.  Any thoughts from others?